# Toolbar width limited by menu items

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I want to create a toolbar with a custom layout. The layout should have an image, title and tabs. It should have a similar structure to the following example:

[image]

My problem is that the menu items make the toolbar boundaries too narrow. I need the full toolbar's width without dependency from the menu items.
My toolbar looks like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTransparent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarLight">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_league_icon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/league_image"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_league"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
            app:border_width="1dp"
            app:shadow="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_league_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv_league_icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_league_icon"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            android:hint="@string/enter_league_name"
            tools:text="My League"
            tools:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The main area of the layout (relative layout) should be spread out on the entire available width of the toolbar. The menu icons cause the layout to narrow, and as a result the relative layout also narrows.

Comment: Hey! Did you managed to solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I used 2 separate toolbars one after the other inside a linear layout. The second one was the one which contains all the content